# tellg() and seekg (c++) for java (files)

Tags: java, file

I need change offset of file in java(for read)
in c++ we have tellg() and seekg for change offset of file
what can I do for java?
I try to bufferedreader2=bufferedreader1 but when I change offset of bufferedreader2 by readline() ,offset of  bufferedreader1 is changed!!

excuse me.my English is not very good.

Comment: Do you understand that the values of `bufferedReader2` and `bufferedReader1` are just references to the same object? This is a far more fundamental concept to understand than anything to do with file IO.

Comment: I think you should include your code along with a better description of what you are trying to read.  You might not need Java methods which are exact parallels of something in C++.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an `InputStream` / `Reader` for that, since they are for sequential access only.

The old style would be to use [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) (Java 1+).

The new style would be to use [`SeekableByteChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel.html) (Java 7+).

Note that both are *byte* offsets, not *character* offsets.

```
// Old style
File file = new File("foo/bar.txt");
RandomAccessFile f = RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
long pos = f.getFilePointer();
f.seek(pos);

// New style
Path path = Paths.get("foo/bar.txt");
SeekableByteChannel ch = Files.newByteChannel(path); // Defaults to read-only
long pos = ch.position();
ch.position(pos);
```

Comment: what is difference of byte offsets & character offsets.?

Comment: I want to read by readline() for read a line.but SeekableByteChannel dont have this object.what can I do for read a line and save in string?

Comment: Depending on the character encoding (charset) of the file, a character may be encoded by multiple bytes, e.g. for 1 byte for [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Code_page_layout), 2 or 4 bytes for [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Description), and between 1 and 6 bytes [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description).